# Unexpected $end in php script?

Tags: php

I have this bit of code that looks fine to me, but I keep getting the following error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in
>   /home/txclanco/public_html/hotmuze/addSong.php on line 21"

This is a script that takes in the input from a form, checks for duplicates and if there is a duplicate, it will not make a new row but just add 1 to the 'rating' row where the songname is the song typed in. If there isn't a duplicate, the script will add the data as a new row. The data types are:

- id = A_I/int
- songname = varchar
- artist = varchar
- rating = int

**The script is below with the mysql data blanked out:**

```
<?
  mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("***") or die(mysql_error());
  $songname = $_POST['songname'];
  $artist = $_POST['by'];
  $ratenum = 1; 
  $chkquery = "SELECT * FROM hotmuze WHERE songname='$songname'";
  $plusOneQuery = "SELECT * FROM hotmuze WHERE songname='$songname'";
  $updateQuery = "UPDATE hotmuze SET rating='$rating2' WHERE songname='$songname'";
  $checkdata = mysql_query($chkquery);
  $checkrows = mysql_num_rows($checkdata); 

  if($checkrows==0) 
  {
      $insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze (id, songname, artist, rating) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '$ratenum'";
      $insdata = mysql_query($insquery); 
  }

  if($checkrows!=0) 
  { 
    $plusData = mysql_query($plusOneQuery);
  }

  if(mysql_num_rows($plusData)!=0) 
  {
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($plusData);
    $rating = $result['ratng'];
    $rating2 = $rating + 1;
    mysql_query($updateQuery); 
    echo "Data Inserted";
  } 
?>
```

Line 21 being:

```
if($checkrows!=0) 
{
  // The brace is on line 21
  $plusData = mysql_query($plusOneQuery);
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with the script? I know the Unexpected $end error usually means that there's a brace out of place, but this time, it's fine?

Comment: Your current error aside, your `$insquery` seems to be declared with a bracket missing at the end of the SQL.

Comment: You really need `mysql_real_escape_string` those vars before putting them in the query :-)

Comment: Your code parses just fine. Did you remove the syntax error when blanking out MySQL credentials?

Comment: @Johnathan: Thanks! That was one of the few problems, haha. I redid it with a new structure, it works fine :) Thanks! :)

@prodigitalson: Will do :D The script is a tester for me only, and I usually apply security measures later :D haha, thanks :)

@AlvaroG: Really? lol, doubt that :S Thanks anyways! Solved it :D

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 $insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze (id, songname, artist, rating) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '$ratenum'";
```

to

```
$insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze (id, songname, artist, rating) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '$ratenum')";
```

you have missed the `)` at end

Comment: if you got any errors in query execution lines. check the root of that. you will find error clear. moreover `unexpected $end` is for any  incomplete closing

Comment: Thanks, that was one problem, and there were others. I redid the script with a different structure, and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

VALUES open and close '()' is need

```
    $insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze (id, songname, artist, rating) 
VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '$ratenum')";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was one problem, and there were others. I redid the script with a different structure, and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of opening brackets you have against the number of closing brackets.

$insquery = "INSERT INTO hotmuze (id, songname, artist, rating) VALUES('', '$songname', '$artist', '$ratenum')";

Comment: Thanks, I usually use Notepad++ to do it, but eh :P The Web Editor I use is horrible :( That wasn't the only problem somehow! Either way, I redid the whole code in a different structure, and it worked! Thanks anyways! :)c